# Rubygems and the wheel group

Tags: ruby, macos, permissions

When I try

```
gem install compass
```

I get an error

> You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory

When I run `ls -la` I get this

```
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel  238 21 Jan 15:08 2.0.0
```

Should it be in the 'wheel' group? If not - how can I fix?

Answer (score 1):

Do you just need to install as root or by using `sudo`?

```
sudo gem install compass
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer installing gems per user rather than system wide. Then you never have to worry about permissions or version conflicts. You can do that with

```
gem install compass --user-install
```